# ConstraintException when querying SQlite database with C#

Tags: c#, database, database-design, sqlite

I’m hoping somebody will be able to help with my SQLite database problem.

I’m receiving a `ConstraintException` when querying my SQLite database with C#. The full exception message is “`Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.`” I originally built this database using access which worked fine, but for various reasons I had to recreate it using SQLite.

To give a bit of background - this is a simple status scheduling program. Each `Status` has an associated `Account` and `Schedule`. I realise `Statuses` and `Schedule` is a 1:1 relationship and could be in the same table but to allow the program to develop further I have split them into two tables.

See below for a cut down version of my table script (this is enough to recreate the problem).

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE Accounts
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Name char(100));

CREATE TABLE Statuses
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
AccountId INTEGER REFERENCES Accounts(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
Text char(140));

CREATE TABLE Schedule
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Statuses(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
StartDate char(255),
Frequency INT);
```

I did not have any issues until I created two `Statues` and associated them to the same `Account`.

```
Accounts
ID  Name
1   Fred Blogs

Statuses
ID AccountId Text
1         1          “Some text”
2         1          “Some more text”

Schedule
ID    StartDate     Frequency
1     16/02/2011        1
2     16/02/2011        1
```

The select statement I’m using which throws the exception is:

```
SELECT Statuses.Id, Statuses.Text, Accounts.Id, Accounts.Name, Schedule.StartDate, Schedule.Frequency
FROM [Statuses], [Accounts], [Schedule]
WHERE Statuses.AccountId = Accounts.Id AND Statuses.Id = Schedule.Id
```

If I run the same query, but remove the ‘`Accounts.Id`’ column the query works fine.

See below for the C# code I’m using but I don’t think this is the problem

```
public DataTable Query(string commandText)
    {

        SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
        SQLiteCommand sqliteCom = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, sqliteCon);
        DataTable sqliteResult = new DataTable("Query Result");

        try
        {
            sqliteCon.Open();
            sqliteResult.Load(sqliteCom.ExecuteReader());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqliteCon.Close();
        }

        return sqliteResult;

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way round this problem. If I select the AccountId from the Schedule table rather than the Accounts table there is no exception thrown. It seems I was unable to run a SELECT statement that contained two Unique primary key columns.

So instead of

```
SELECT Statuses.Id, Statuses.Text, Accounts.Id, Accounts.Name, Schedule.StartDate, Schedule.Frequency
FROM [Statuses], [Accounts], [Schedule]
WHERE Statuses.AccountId = Accounts.Id AND Statuses.Id = Schedule.Id
```

I run

```
SELECT Statuses.Id, Statuses.Text, Statuses.AccountId, Accounts.Name, Schedule.StartDate, Schedule.Frequency
FROM [Statuses], [Accounts], [Schedule]
WHERE Statuses.AccountId = Accounts.Id AND Statuses.Id = Schedule.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

the error is occuring due to  the ID columns in Statuses table and Schedule table. If they are not important delete the columns from the two tables.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The Id columns are important as I need to link a Schedule to a Status. Each Status has a corresponding Schedule. For example Status with Id 1 is linked to Schedule with Id 1. The Schedule Id is a foreign key. Also I'm not sure the problem is related to the Schedule table as the issue only appears when I select [Account.Id] along with [Status.Id]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by reading the schema only at first, then cleared the constraints of the datatable and then read again the data. 
like this :

```
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
mytable = new DataTable();
DS.Tables.Add(mytable);
DS.EnforceConstraints = false;
SQLiteCommand command = DBconnection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select * from V_FullView";
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
mytable.Load(reader);
mytable.Constraints.Clear();
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
mytable.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
```

my V_FullView is a view of 4 different tables merged. It seems that the constraints are the ones of the first merged table (name was unique on that one, but replicated a multiple of times in the view)